# Discordjs messagecollector Select a specific channel

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I want to make a message collector for a specific channel to log all the messages, the problem is that I get the channel ID and I create a colletor but it throws an error that the function doesn't exist.

```js
client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
    btcValue().then((value) => {
        client.user.setActivity(`BTC: ${value}`);
    });

    const filter = (m) => m.content.includes("discord");
    const channelGeneral = client.channels.fetch("CHANNEL_ID");
    console.log(channelgeneral);
    const collector = channelGeneral.createMessageCollector(filter);

    collector.on("collect", (m) => {
        console.log(`Cocollector: ${m.content}`);
    });
});
```